# Using subs and audio embedded in video in html video

Tags: html, mp4

I have a video file with 2 audios, say audio1 and audio2, and subtitles s1 and s2. I want to stream this video through `<video>` tag in html and let the user change audio stream and subtitle stream as per their suiting. So far I havent found anything that suits my need and all I found was to add subs to the `<video>` instead of using from the video itself. Can I get some pointers if this is actually possible? And how?

Comment: A `video` tag will play a single source file - it won't glue together a composite as you describe. You'd need to play the video in mute, and then have some hidden `audio` tag to handle the audio and which audio stream should play. You'd obviously then have to keep these two media elements in sync in terms of play position.

Comment: ooh! thanks man. i will have to come up with something else

Comment: But what about subs? subs embedded into the video can be used or they have to be off-loaded as well?

Comment: There's no cross-browser implementation for subtitles yet, AFAIK. There are JS implementations. Video platforms like Vimeo and YouTube provide the means to add multiple subtitle channels and then the user can select one (or you can stipulate one programmatically) in the player itself.